# How to deploy RDS Serverless Aurora using Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

Aurora Serverless MySQL is now [generally available](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aurora-serverless-ga/), and I wanted to change my cloudformation to include the new key, `engineMode`, which is in the [boto3 docs](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/rds.html) which can be set to either "provisioned", or "serverless".

I assumed that because it was supported in boto3, and nearly all the params to deploy it via boto3 are usually properties in the cloudformation template, however I didn't see in the [cloudformation RDS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-dbcluster.html). So I tried the following:

```
RDSSubnetGroup:
Type: AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup
Properties:
  DBSubnetGroupDescription: Inventory RDS Subnet Group
  SubnetIds: !Ref SubnetIds

DatabaseCluster:
Type: AWS::RDS::DBCluster
Properties:
  Engine: aurora
  EngineMode: serverless
  MasterUsername:
    Ref: DBMasterUserName
  MasterUserPassword:
    Ref: DBPassword
  BackupRetentionPeriod:
    Ref: DBBackupRetentionPeriod
  DatabaseName: credentials
  DBSubnetGroupName: !Ref RDSSubnetGroup
  StorageEncrypted: True

DatabasePrimaryInstance:
Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
Properties:
  Engine: aurora
  EngineMode: serverless
  DBInstanceClass:
    Ref: InstanceType
  DBClusterIdentifier:
    Ref: DatabaseCluster
  DBSubnetGroupName: !Ref RDSSubnetGroup
  StorageEncrypted: True
```

but I get an error on cloudformation: `Encountered unsupported property EngineMode`

Comment: having the same issue. The docs have 'EngineMode' option but clooudformation is rejecting the parameter. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_CreateDBCluster.html

Comment: Which region? Serverless is not available in all regions as of today. Typically for Europe only Ireland has this option

Comment: good answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51879688/creating-an-aurora-serverless-cluster-from-cloudformation