# How to create an Aurora Serverless DB cluster using AWS-CDK (java or typescript) aditionally connected with lambda to query some data?

Tags: aws-serverless, amazon-aurora, aws-cdk

I am seaching for an example to create an Aurora Serverless DB cluster created with new AWS-CDK (based on Java or typescript). Additionaly the example should create a lambda function using a connection to DB cluster and query some data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first try was to create this with

```
software.amazon.awscdk.services.rds.DatabaseCluster
```

for example

```
DatabaseCluster databaseCluster = new DatabaseCluster(this, "myDbCluster",
    DatabaseClusterProps.builder()
        .withEngine(DatabaseClusterEngine.Aurora)
```

But according to cloudformation you have to set property `engineMode` to `serverless`. The property `engineMode` ist not supported in CDK version 0.24.1. See also open cdk Issue [929](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cdk/issues/929).

The Workaround for me ist to create the construct using `software.amazon.awscdk.services.rds.CfnDBCluster`. See example code:

```
new CfnDBCluster(this, "myDBCluster", CfnDBClusterProps.builder()
    .withEngine("aurora")
     .withEngineMode("serverless")
    .withPort(3306)
    .withMasterUsername("masterUserName")
    .withMasterUserPassword("***********************")
    .withScalingConfiguration(ScalingConfigurationProperty.builder()
        .withAutoPause(true)
        .withMinCapacity(2)
        .withMaxCapacity(16)
        .withSecondsUntilAutoPause(300)
        .build())
    .build());
```

See also:

[Creating an Aurora Serverless Cluster from cloudformation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51879688/creating-an-aurora-serverless-cluster-from-cloudformation)

[AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-dbcluster.html](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-dbcluster.html)

https://awslabs.github.io/aws-cdk/refs/_aws-cdk_aws-rds.html

Answer (score 3):

I know you asked for Java or TypeScript example, but my mother tongue is Python and so I only have a Python example for you. Amazon documentation does provide further details on how to "translate" CDK code from one language to another - it's fairly straightforward. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/multiple_languages.html

The below example creates an Aurora cluster with a PostgreSQL engine. It creates an admin user ('admin') with password which is retrieved from a (previously created) SSM secure string parameter. It also creates an initial database within the cluster called 'MyDatabase'.

It also (first) creates a Lambda, assuming that the code for the handler is already in `lambda-handler.py`, puts that in a security group and ensures that Aurora exposes the DB port to the lambda security group.

All of this is in the context of a VPC.

Code follows:

```
from aws_cdk import aws_ec2 as ec2
from aws_cdk import aws_rds as rds
from aws_cdk import aws_lambda as lambda_
from aws_cdk import core


class DataProcessingRTStack(core.Stack):
    def __init__(self, scope: core.Construct, id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, id, **kwargs)

        vpc = ec2.Vpc.from_lookup(self, 'VPC', vpc_name="my_vpc")

        lambda_sg = kwargs.pop('lambda_sg', None)

        with open("lambda-handler.py", encoding="utf8") as fp:
            handler_code = fp.read()

        lambda_fn = lambda_.Function(
            self, "DB_Lambda",
            code=lambda_.InlineCode(handler_code),
            handler="index.main",
            timeout=core.Duration.seconds(300),
            runtime=lambda_.Runtime.PYTHON_3_7,
            security_group=lambda_sg,
        )

        aurora_sg = ec2.SecurityGroup(
            self, 'AUPG-SG',
            vpc=vpc,
            description="Allows PosgreSQL connections from Lambda SG",
        )
        aurora_cluster = rds.DatabaseCluster(
            self, "AUPG-CLUSTER-1",
            engine=rds.DatabaseClusterEngine.AURORA_POSTGRESQL,
            engine_version="10.7",
            master_user=rds.Login(
                username='admin', 
                password=core.SecretValue.ssm_secure('AUPG.AdminPass', version='1'),
            ),
            default_database_name='MyDatabase',
            instance_props=rds.InstanceProps(
                instance_type=ec2.InstanceType.of(
                    ec2.InstanceClass.MEMORY5, ec2.InstanceSize.XLARGE,
                ),
                vpc=vpc,
                security_group=aurora_sg,
            ), 
            parameter_group=\
                rds.ClusterParameterGroup.from_parameter_group_name(
                self, "AUPG-ParamGroup-1",
                parameter_group_name="default.aurora-postgresql10",
            )
        )
        aurora_cluster.connections.allow_from(
            connectors_sg, ec2.Port.tcp(3306),
            "Allow MySQL access from Lambda (because Aurora actually exposes PostgreSQL on port 3306)",
        )
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question - OP is looking for how to create an Aurora Serverless cluster, but your example shows a normal Aurora cluster