# Fail to create a custom domain name for websocket API gateway using AWS Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I need to create a custom domain name for a websocket enabled API gateway and seems that CloudFormation for API gateway v2 (which is basically for websocket) doesn’t support it (at least the documentation  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-reference-apigatewayv2.html  doesn’t mention this). I tried with `AWS::ApiGateway::DomainName` which I believe is for Rest API gateway but the stack fails with the error

> This custom domain name cannot map to WEBSOCKET protocol Apis.

I see that AWS CLI does support API gateway v2 create domain name command (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigatewayv2/create-domain-name.html) but not sure the reason why the CloudFormation wouldn’t support this.

Any workaround or feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the way it works is that new *features* first appear in CLI or APIs and are added to CFN later on. Why? Because I believe CFN uses the same API internally to create the resource with given properties. Here's a similar thread with same experience for when Aurora Serverless was released. [Creating an Aurora serverless cluster from cloudformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51879688/creating-an-aurora-serverless-cluster-from-cloudformation)

Workaround - create a lambda backed [AWS::CloudFormation::CustomResource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cfn-customresource.html) & call the [createDomainName](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigatewayv2/latest/api-reference/domainnames.html#domainnamespost) API from the lambda to create your custom domain name. Sometime in the future, it probably will be made available in cloudformation.

Update: No need for lambda custom resource. [Better answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60685063/custom-domain-name-for-websockets-api-with-serverless/61834163#61834163)

Answer (score 2):

No more need of lambda, https://stackoverflow.com/a/61834163/9799292

This Cloud Formation template is working just fine

```yaml
Resources:
    WebSocketDomainName:
      Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::DomainName
      Properties:
        DomainName: <domain-name>
        DomainNameConfigurations:
          - EndpointType: 'REGIONAL'
            CertificateArn: <cert-arn>
    WebSocketMapping:
      Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::ApiMapping
      Properties:
        ApiId: <app-id>
        DomainName: !Ref WebSocketDomainName
        Stage: <stage-name>
```