# Custom Domain Name for WebSockets API with Serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I'm managing a REST API for an app with Serverless and want to extend this setup with a WebSockets API in the same region. Everything should be handled with the same certificate, but different subdomains.

At first I created a new custom domain with `sls create_domain --stage=...`.
Then I tried to add it to the new WebSockets stack, but ended with this error:

> Error: Failed to find CloudFormation resources for ...

I found it on Github that this seems to be not supported by CloudFormation right now so Serverless does not support it.

So I tried to attach my stage to the custom domain name manually in the UI:

> Mixing of REST APIs and HTTP APIs on the same domain name can only be
>   accomplished through API Gateway's V2 DomainName interface. Currently,
>   WebSocket APIs can only be attached to a domain name with other
>   WebSocket APIs. This must also occur through API Gateway's V2
>   DomainName interface.

More confusion arises, as it's not even the same domain name in this case. The new domain name was `sockets.<DOMAIN>.com` and the existing one was `api.<DOMAIN>.com`. Or do different subdomains are falling into 'same domain name'?

Nevertheless I tried to create the custom domain again via the apigatewayv2 CLI:

```
aws apigatewayv2 create-domain-name --domain-name <DOMAIN> --domain-name-configurations file://domain-configuration.json --region eu-west-1
```

domain-configuration.json:

```
[
{
    "ApiGatewayDomainName": "<DOMAIN>",
    "CertificateArn": "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:<ACCOUNT_ID>:certificate/<CERT_ID>",
    "CertificateName": "<DOMAIN>",
    "DomainNameStatus": "AVAILABLE",
    "EndpointType": "EDGE",
    "SecurityPolicy": "TLS_1_2"
}
```

]

But this results in the following error:

> An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the CreateDomainName operation: Invalid certificate ARN: arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:924441585974:certificate/b88f0a3f-1393-4a16-a876-9830852b5207. Certificate must be in 'eu-west-1'.

My current state was that API Gateway only allows custom certificates to be located in us-east-1, so this error confuses me even more.

**Summary**: I'm completely stuck on how to get a custom domain name attached to my WebSocket API stage. I'm happy about every hint in the right direction!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found a solution with a custom CloudFormation resource template:

```
resources:
  Resources:
    WebSocketDomainName:
      Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::DomainName
      Properties:
        DomainName: <domain-name>
        DomainNameConfigurations:
          - EndpointType: 'REGIONAL'
            CertificateArn: <cert-arn>
    WebSocketMapping:
      Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::ApiMapping
      Properties:
        ApiId: <api-id>
        DomainName: !Ref WebSocketDomainName
        Stage: <stage-name>
    DNSRecord:
      Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSet
      Properties:
        HostedZoneName: <hosted-zone-name>.
        TTL: '900'
        ResourceRecords:
          - !GetAtt [ WebSocketDomainName, RegionalDomainName ]
        Name: <domain-name>
        Type: CNAME
```

**Edit**: Now working with [serverless-domain-manager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-domain-manager?activeTab=readme)!

```
custom:
  customDomain:
    rest:
      domainName: rest.serverless.foo.com
      stage: ci
      basePath: api
      certificateName: '*.foo.com'
      createRoute53Record: true
      endpointType: 'regional'
      securityPolicy: tls_1_2
    http:
      domainName: http.serverless.foo.com
      stage: ci
      basePath: api
      certificateName: '*.foo.com'
      createRoute53Record: true
      endpointType: 'regional'
      securityPolicy: tls_1_2
    websocket:
      domainName: ws.serverless.foo.com
      stage: ci
      basePath: api
      certificateName: '*.foo.com'
      createRoute53Record: true
      endpointType: 'regional'
      securityPolicy: tls_1_2
```

Comment: Working for me with just first two ressources and Cloudflare

Comment: "An error occurred: WebSocketMapping - Currently, WebSocket APIs cannot be mixed with REST APIs or HTTP APIs on the same domain name. (Service: AmazonApiGatewayV2;" Has WebSocket Mapping with HTTP been depreciated for v2..?

Comment: @JasonMullings have you found a solution ?

Comment: @MFAL Sorry, there is no solution here, AWS doesn't allow.
I would suggest moving away from SLS as a Websocket solution, as the costs are seriously high per innvocation. Stick with an EC2 instance...

Answer (score 4):

Thanks @tpschmidt for the helpful response!
Just to add, in case you want a BasePathMapping for your websocket domain, add ApiMappingKey to the Cloudformation provided above. E.g.:

```
WebSocketMapping:
      Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::ApiMapping
      Properties:
        ApiId: <api-id>
        DomainName: !Ref WebSocketDomainName
        Stage: <stage-name>
        ApiMappingKey: <stage-name> #(e.g. prod)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to make a couple of minor adjustments to have a Lambda in a private VPC with WebSockets support and a custom domain.

1. The `CertificateArn` must be from ACM and **cannot** be a certificate uploaded to IAM.
2. I used an A-record instead of a CNAME

```
WebSocketDomainName:
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::DomainName
    Properties:
        DomainName: !Ref DomainName
        DomainNameConfigurations:
            - EndpointType: REGIONAL
              CertificateArn: <your-certificate-arn>

# This maps /staging or /prod to just the domain name
WebSocketMapping:
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::ApiMapping
    Properties:
        ApiId: <your-api-id>
        DomainName: !Ref WebSocketDomainName
        Stage: <your-stage>

Route53DNS:
    Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup
    Properties:
        HostedZoneName: !Ref Route53HostedZone
        RecordSets:
            - Name: !Ref DomainName
              Type: A
              AliasTarget:
                  HostedZoneId: ZLY8HYME6SFDD # This means eu-west-1 ApiGateWay
                  DNSName:
                      !GetAtt [WebSocketDomainName, RegionalDomainName]
```

For your `HostedZoneId` check: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/apigateway.html