# Cloudformation to create an RDS cluster with engine aurora-postgresql and enginemode: serverless

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-aurora

I am trying to create an amazon RDS cluster using cloudformation.  The two properties I'm having trouble with are `Engine: aurora-postgresql` and `EngineMode: serverless`

Here is my template:

```
  AuroraDBCluster:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBCluster
    DeletionPolicy: Snapshot
    UpdateReplacePolicy: Snapshot
    Properties:
      BackupRetentionPeriod: 7
      DatabaseName: MyDBNameHere
      DBClusterParameterGroupName: !Ref RDSDBClusterParameterGroup
      DBSubnetGroupName: !Ref DBSubnetGroup
      EnableHttpEndpoint: true
      Engine: aurora-postgresql
      EngineMode: serverless
      EngineVersion: 11.7      
      MasterUsername:
        shhhh
      MasterUserPassword:
        bequiet
      Port: 5432
      VpcSecurityGroupIds:
      - !Ref MyReferenceHere
```

I know this is similar to [Creating an Aurora Serverless Cluster from cloudformation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51879688/4946843),
but my understanding is that setting `Engine: aurora` is used for MySql not for postgresql.

I'm running this with Bitbucket pipelines and getting an error.
`The engine mode serverless you requested is currently unavailable.`

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason could be that you are using PostgreSQL  11.7.

From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.html#aurora-serverless.limitations),  `Aurora Serverless` only supports:

> Aurora with PostgreSQL **version 10.7** compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

My full, working Aurora Postgres serverless DBCluster resource is:

```
  RDSCluster:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBCluster
    Properties:
      DBClusterIdentifier: !Ref DBClusterName
      MasterUsername: some-name
      MasterUserPassword: some-password
      DatabaseName: some-db-name
      Engine: aurora-postgresql
      EngineMode: serverless
      EngineVersion: '10' # this currently provisions '10.serverless_14'
      ScalingConfiguration:
        AutoPause: true
        MaxCapacity: 2
        MinCapacity: 2 # min 2 currently
        SecondsUntilAutoPause: 900 # 15 min
      DBSubnetGroupName:
        Ref: DBSubnetGroup
```